# Explanation of unknown type (literally named <Module>), in ModuleDefinition

Tags: c#, mono.cecil

I have been experimenting with MONO.CECIL for altering assemblies.

I have a simple assembly to test my code manipulation techniques on, shown below (SIMPLE ASSEMBLY).
I also have another assembly which acts upon it (SIMPLE ASSEMBLY INSPECTOR). Currently I am only using it to inspect the assembly and print out its internals.

When looping through the Types contained in the ModuleDefinition associated with the assembly I have two entries : one for the class FAUXASSEMBLY and the other is simply called MODULE (0 Fields, 0 Parameters). I am unsure what MODULE pertains to.

Can someone please explain its significance and what it represents? Thankyou.

SIMPLE ASSEMBLY

```
namespace TestAssembly
{
    public static class FauxAssembly
    {
        static int var1 = 20;
        static string var2 = "Hello I Am A String";
        static int FauxPrint()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("PRINTING");
            Console.WriteLine("Var1 is : {0}, Var2 is : {1}", var1, var2);
            return 0;
        }
     static void FauxMain()
        {
            FauxPrint();
            Console.WriteLine("ENDING NOW");
        }
   }
}
```

SIMPLE ASSEMBLY INSPECTOR

```
        Mono.Cecil.AssemblyDefinition assembly = 
            AssemblyDefinition.ReadAssembly(path + filename, new ReaderParameters 
            { ReadWrite = true, InMemory = true});
        Mono.Cecil.ModuleDefinition module = assembly.MainModule;
        Helper.PrintModule(module);
        foreach (TypeDefinition type in module.Types)
        {
            Helper.PrintType(type);
        }
```

Comment: `<Module>` (angle brackets and not all caps) is the name of in internal class where global declarations are stored.  It is usually empty, in general only C++/CLI projects add definitions there.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/3796999/17034

Comment: Thankyou for this, appreciated.